# How can I split a line in 2 by words/characters? (Bash) (Regex)

Tags: bash, regex, awk

I would like to convert:

```
Hello Hello Hi Hello Hello Hi Hi Hi Hi Hello
```

To:

```
Hello Hello Hi Hello
Hello Hi Hi Hi Hi Hello
```

I want to split a single line in 2, by **having them have the closest amount of characters as possible, without cutting off a word.**

I think I can probably do it with wc -w, wc -c, cut, and/or awk, but maybe you guys can provide some better ideas!

Comment: This question is cross-posted on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378720/how-can-i-split-a-line-in-2-by-words-characters-bash-regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't give much more information so I'm assuming you have your string in a variable called `YOUR_STRING`. This can easily be adapted to process files and whatnot.

First determine half the length of your string, and add 1 (otherwise you end up with 3 lines and not 2):

```
CHARS=$((`echo $YOUR_STRING | wc -c` /2 + 1))
```

Next, use the `fold` command to wrap your text:

```
echo $YOUR_STRING | fold -sw $CHARS
```

Result:

```
Hello Hello Hi Hello 
Hello Hi Hi Hi Hi Hello
```

See `man fold` for more information.

Comment: Perfect, thank you, I asked this at stackoverflow, and I got a very similar answer using fold. Never knew about fold, glad to know about it now.
By any chance is fold portable and is it common in many Linux distros?

Comment: `echo | wc` is useless here. There are important quotes missing. This doesn't really show good practice. Also, be aware that `fold` counts _bytes_ and not _characters_. So you will definitely get 3 lines or more if there are any wide characters.

Comment: gniourf_gniourf, what is considered a "wide" character?
Will it be a problem for characters between a-z and A-Z?

Comment: gniourf_gniourf you're more than welcome to propose an alternative showing good practice and proper character counting, that would be quite helpful and constructive and would help us all learn more.

Comment: @user264974 the characters in the ranges A-Z and a-z are not wide characters, so it'll work fine with these.

Comment: Good practice: 1. don't use uppercase variable names. 2. To get the number of characters in a string, use: `chars=${#your_string}`. Since you want half plus one: `chars=$((${#your_string}/2+1))`. This saves a subshell and a fork to external program (and saves from pathname expansion with your unquoted `echo $YOUR_STRING`). 3. Use more quotes: `echo "$your_string" | fold -sw "$chars"`. Without the quotes for `$your_string`, you'll get surprises if your string contains glob characters like `?`, `*`, `[...]` and extglobs constructs too if `extglob` is set.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf thanks, that's quite useful. Could you please cite a source for item #1, since that doesn't look like a technical issue, but a stylistic one?

Comment: [This](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet#Parameters) and [this](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/style#variable_names). The main idea is that reserved variable names are in uppercase. If you use uppercase in your own variable names, you will one day have problems if you define `PATH` or `HOME`, etc. It actually happens very often that users define the variable `PATH` and then wonder why their script stops working all of a sudden. Latest to date is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29387616/bash-xargs-command-not-found

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Thanks, much appreciated and the rationale makes a lot of sense.